# Conditional Formatting with Reference Formula

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on code that uses Excel buttons to run code. The purpose of this code is to insert a formatted line so that a technical can fill out data values as needed. This way the technician can keep adding as many lines as need.

For one of the test that the technician is performing I want the value to be conditional formatted grey if it is below a certain threshold. The issue with this is that because I keep inserting cell lines into excel I can not reference the same location. I placed buttons to insert these lines and I am using the button location as a reference. Is there any way to use FormulaR1C1 or a different method to make this happen?

My code looks like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim V_Val As Variant ' Make the voltage value a variable
Dim rs As Integer ' The push button location
Dim cs As Integer

V_Val = InputBox("Voltage Above")                           ' Ask user input
rs = ActiveSheet.Shapes("CommandButton2").TopLeftCell.Row   ' Get push button location
cs = ActiveSheet.Shapes("CommandButton2").TopLeftCell.Column

Worksheets("Format3").Rows("7:7").Copy                      'Always grab from the same location
Worksheets("Meas_sum").Rows(rs).Insert Shift:=xlDown

ActiveSheet.Cells(rs, cs + 1).Select                    ' Place the voltage value in
Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
Selection.Value = V_Val

    ' Sig Pulse Grey out code
Range(Cells(rs, cs + 16), Cells(rs, cs + 29)).Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, _
        ActiveSheet.Cells(r2 + 2, c2 + i).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C/R[-2]C"
        'Formula1:="=G6*1.5>Q6" 'Make above work from refference value
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = -0.499984740745262
    End With
```

Comment: Is there an unique identifier for this test (line)? Perhaps column A or the label (cell) above always starts with voltage xyz? If so, do an if statement for it and format accordingly.